# MSSQL Medals Awarded in doubles Brain Teaser

Tags: sql-server

I need a way to calculate medals for doubles events with data that looks like this.

```
registered|Event_Name|gender_name|Participation_Name

5|Badminton Doubles|Male|Doubles

1|Badminton Doubles|Male|Doubles

3|Bowling Doubles|Female|Doubles
```

The problem is that medals (gold, silver, and bronze get awarded to each doubles team).

So in the first row for badminton when there are 5 participants I should have 2 golds, 2 silvers, and 1 bronze.

For the second row I should have 1 gold, 0 silver, and 0 bronze.

For the third row I should have 2 golds, 1 silver and 0 bronze.

What SQL magic can I used to do this calculation?

Comment: You provide 4 column names but 5 columns of data, what sits between event name and gender name? Also, what do you want the output to look like? What have you tried so far? This looks like a homework question.

May want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: This is a real life problem in a project I am working on currently.  I greatly simplified the data to be able to show it in the question.  Sorry about the extra column, I just removed it.  The output could be in any fashion.  It could be one select with golds, silvers, bronzes or returned as 3 seperate variables.  My problem is how to calculate gold, silver and bronze knowing the number of total participants.  I really only put the data in here to give context to the question but looking at it now I probably should have just left it out all together.

Comment: My guess is you have a table for individual participants, a table for teams (linked to participants), a table for events and a table for results (with the event, team and score or placing) or some variation of that. One basic idea would be to do a join the tables and use something like a `dr = dense_rank() over (partition by team order by result)` then use that to have something like this in a select statement: `case when dr = 1 then 'gold' when dr = 2 then 'silver' when dr = 3 then 'bronze' end`.

Comment: Hey ZLK,  that was a really good stab at the structure of the tables.  That is the basic gist of what I have but there are about 15 more tables involved to get the data because of the complexity of this system.  I hadn't thought about trying to partition the data yet.  I had been trying to do everything in my select.  I will give that a shot to see if that will work.

Comment: The dense rank is done _on_ a result set. So, e.g., if your select statement is like `select person, team from mytable...` etc you can change it to something like `select person, team, medal = case dense_rank() over (partition by team order by result) when 1 then 'gold' when 2 then 'silver when 3 then 'bronze' end from mytable...`

Answer (score 0):

I just used 3 case statements, one for each medal. I don't know how scalable this is, but it should work for this use case.

```
,case
    when registered >= 2 then 2
    else registered
    end as gold
,case
    when registered >= 4 then 2
    when registered <= 2 then 0
    else 1
    end as silver
,case
    when registered >= 6 then 2
    when registered <= 4 then 0
    else 1
    end as bronze
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help with this Andrew,

This gave me the idea of doing this case statement over each row into a new temp table and then summing the doubles medal counts together.

This is the result in case anyone runs into this issue.

```
    --get our singles medal counts for singles which is very simple
        set @goldsingles = (select count(registered) from #registered where registered > 0 and Participation_Name = 'Singles')
        set @silversingles = (select count(registered) from #registered where registered > 1 and Participation_Name = 'Singles')
        set @bronzesingles = (select count(registered) from #registered where registered > 2 and Participation_Name = 'Singles')

        --select our doubles data into a new temp table so that we can 
        --get medal counts for each event and then sum those all up
        select * 
        into #registereddoubles
        from #registered 
        where Participation_Name = 'Doubles' or Participation_Name = 'Mixed Doubles'

        --add columns to store the medal count for each event based on doubles logic
        alter table #registereddoubles 
        add doublesgold int not null default(0), doublessilver int not null default(0), doublesbronze int not null default(0);

        --update our events for the doubles golds
        --we want to up the number of medals for a partner even if a participant doesn't have a partner assigned yet
        update #registereddoubles 
        set doublesgold = (case when registered >= 1 then 2 else 0 end)

        update #registereddoubles 
        set doublessilver = (case when registered >= 3 then 2 else 0 end)
        from #registereddoubles rd2

        update #registereddoubles 
        set doublesbronze = (case when registered >= 5 then 2 else 0 end)
        from #registereddoubles rd2

        set @golddoubles = (select sum(doublesgold) from #registereddoubles )
        set @silverdoubles = (select sum(doublessilver) from #registereddoubles )
        set @bronzedoubles = (select sum(doublesbronze) from #registereddoubles )

        select @gold = @goldsingles + @golddoubles
        select @silver = @silversingles + @silverdoubles
        select @bronze = @bronzesingles + @bronzedoubles

        --select * from #registereddoubles

        --select * from #registered
        drop table #registered
        drop table #registereddoubles
```

Now I have to do a much more complicated scenario for team sports but it will follow this same idea of creating a temp table where the medals counts for each team event will kept.